# How to solve error message python webcrawler?

Tags: python, web-crawler

any idea how to solve this issue? I have a bulk of similar webpages (list of URLs is already fetched) I would like to scrape but I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-c44d70d4fe49> in <module>
      1 #Pull page details
----> 2 pullpagedetails(take1)

<ipython-input-42-6ae0e26aee16> in pullpagedetails(Url_list)
     42             #Testing if URL contains necessary elements
     43             test_list = []
---> 44             test = call.find_all('p',class_ = re.compile('p p*'))
     45             for c in test:
     46                 x = c.text.strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Duplicate: [NoneType has no attribute](/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)